# Pandas Series from DataFrame columns when the index column contains duplicates

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

The following extraction from a CSV read into pandas as `pd`:

```
return pd.Series((wb['impressions'].values * 1.0)/(wb['ad_requests'].values * 1.0), index=wb['\xef\xbb\xbf"ad_tag_name"']).to_dict()
```

is no longer valid, since now, as per the image below,

1. there are *multiple* entries of the same name in column A (3 of
   *he.com_300x250_bottomloopmobile*, 4 of *he.com_300x250_bottomloopmobile* for example)
2. column C will be always be blank for *all but the first entry* for each
   unique value.

[image]

I need to now **sum** these multiple values per "key" of column A, and do likewise for column C, then plug these back into the division calculation and series creation.

Experimenting with `groupby()` in isolation for the former behaves well (duplicate keys are removed, which is what I want):

```
In [36]: wb.groupby('\xef\xbb\xbf"ad_tag_name"').sum()['impressions']
Out[36]: 
"ad_tag_name"
he.com_300x250_bottomloopmobile                              26752
he.com_300x250_bottomslidemobile                             31217
```

Yet when I add in back in `index=wb['\xef\xbb\xbf"ad_tag_name"']` to try rebuild the full formula, pandas no longer drops the duplicates:

```
In [37]: pd.Series(wb.groupby('\xef\xbb\xbf"ad_tag_name"').sum()['impressions'], index=wb['\xef\xbb\xbf"ad_tag_name"'])
Out[37]: 
"ad_tag_name"
he.com_300x250_bottomloopmobile          26752
he.com_300x250_bottomloopmobile          26752
he.com_300x250_bottomloopmobile          26752
he.com_300x250_bottomslidemobile         31217
he.com_300x250_bottomslidemobile         31217
he.com_300x250_bottomslidemobile         31217
he.com_300x250_bottomslidemobile         31217
```

Assuming the `groupby()` component of the formula can stay as is, how do we tell the series creation to recognize the duplicate keys of the index column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need assign output to `wb` - [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with `sum` aggregate all numeric columns, so no duplicates, last add `as_index=False` for `DataFrame` output:

```
wb = wb.groupby("ad_tag_name", as_index=False).sum()
#alternative solution
#wb = wb.groupby("ad_tag_name").sum().reset_index()
```

---

Sample:

```
wb = pd.DataFrame({'ad_tag_name':['he.com_300x250_bottomloopmobile'] * 3 +
                                 ['he.he.com_300x250_bottomslidemobile'] * 4, 
                   'impressions':[309, 3029,23414,1465,5725,2918,11109],
                    'ad_requests':[37849,np.nan,np.nan, 42300,np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]})

#print (wb)    

wb = wb.groupby('ad_tag_name', as_index=False).sum()
print (wb)
                           ad_tag_name  ad_requests  impressions
0      he.com_300x250_bottomloopmobile      37849.0        26752
1  he.he.com_300x250_bottomslidemobile      42300.0        21217

a = pd.Series((wb['impressions'].values * 1.0)/(wb['ad_requests'].values * 1.0), 
           index=wb['ad_tag_name']).to_dict()

print (a)
{'he.he.com_300x250_bottomslidemobile': 0.50158392434988175, 
'he.com_300x250_bottomloopmobile': 0.70680863431002139}
```

Also for remove `\xef\xbb\xbf` add `encoding='utf-8-sig'` to [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) or upgrade pandas to last version, because this bug is [closed and solved](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/4793).

Comment: Thanks, but you have duplicate values in the final `df`. *impressions* is to be summed, **per unique ad_tag_name**.  Each identical value in column *ad_tag_name* refers to the same entity. So the final df (in your example) should only have 3 rows, one for each of a, b, c.

Comment: Interesting approach, aggregating and summing _all_ columns before applying the calculation. Elegant. Thanks.